# Filter Textbox with Regex in Powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have been coming back to this snippet powershell code for a while and I can't seem to find the solution.  Basically, I have a Textbox in a WinForm and I input names into the textbox like, ckcTsetg, minintKLV, bbcada, tyleass and others.  When I place them into the textbox I click this filter-out button and the following "ckcTsetg, minintKLV," is filtered out which is correct.  The problem I'm having is the others that are not to be filtered out are removed as well or they are never reached.  When I click the filter button my goal is that the text in "$logOutputBox.TEXT" will be filtered-out then the filtered list will pass to the other box "$objOutputBox.TEXT" by $objOutputBox.TEXT = $Numbered.  Instead it is completely filter the whole list..  If I grab the valid names before hand they are passed to the "$objOutputBox.TEXT" no problem.  I tried a few different things but nothing seems to work.  Any ideas?  Thank you for you help!

```
$repeatButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$repeatButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(310,375)
$repeatButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(160,43)
$repeatButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", "10")
$repeatButton.Text = "Filter"
$repeatButton.Add_Click({


$Filtered = $logOutputBox.TEXT
$Numbered = $Filtered.Split("' ")| ? {$_ -notmatch "etg$|^minint|kvmlc*|dsm|les"}
$objOutputBox.TEXT = $Numbered



}) 
$tunerForm.Controls.Add($repeatButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my issue.  Thanks if you started looking into my question I still really appreciate it very much.  If you don't mind and if you did answer the question please post it still.  There might be a better way of doing it and I really just want to learn..

```
$Numbered = $Filtered.Split("`n ", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | ? {$_ -notmatch "etg$|^minint|kvmlc*|dsm|les"}
```

Comment: See I knew I would be back.  The issue I'm running into is that they are filtering every single one of them.  When they are filtered to the other textbox it is stacking some on each other.  Like below

Comment: How do I add an attachment?